# encode Netbios name python

Tags: python, netbios

I would like to encode "ITSATEST" to it's netbios name value in python;
The occurence table and explication are here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194203

I dont know how this could be done easily in python, someone can give me a hand ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map each nibble of the original string, taking its numerical value and offsetting from 'A':

```
encoded_name = ''.join([chr((ord(c)>>4) + ord('A'))
                        + chr((ord(c)&0xF) + ord('A')) for c in original_name])
```

Comment: @joshperry, I presented the first one because it was easy to understand (and easy to write up while my brain was working on the second). Given your and @helpmenet's support of the "smarter" second solution, I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RFC 1001](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1001.html), which defines the encoding.  In section 14.1 "FIRST LEVEL ENCODING" is the algorithm for the encoding, which you could implement directly in Python.

Comment: It's exactly the same thing as the MS link !