# Decode Netbios Name Python

Tags: python, decoding, netbios

I would like to know what would be the best way to do the opposite of this post :
[encode Netbios name python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965065/encode-netbios-name-python)

So to encode, you could use this :

```
encoded_name = ''.join([chr((ord(c)>>4) + ord('A'))
               + chr((ord(c)&0xF) + ord('A')) for c in original_name])
```

But to decode this for example :

```
Netbios_Name= "\x46\x45\x45\x46\x46\x44\x45\x45\x46\x45\x45\x45\x45\x45\x46\x44\x46\x44\x46\x44\x43\x41\x43\x41\x43\x41\x43\x41\x43\x41\x43\x41"
## When correctly reversed, Netbios_Name should output in ASCII : "TESDTDDSSS"
```

I though about the reverse of this function, but i can't figure why it doesn't work.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use this function (taken from [dpkt source code](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/source/browse/trunk/dpkt/netbios.py)):

```
def decode_name(nbname):
    """Return the NetBIOS first-level decoded nbname."""
    if len(nbname) != 32:
        return nbname
    l = []
    for i in range(0, 32, 2):
        l.append(chr(((ord(nbname[i]) - 0x41) << 4) |
                     ((ord(nbname[i+1]) - 0x41) & 0xf)))
    return ''.join(l).split('\x00', 1)[0]
```

So:

```
>> decode_name(Netbios_Name).strip()
'TESDTDDSSS'
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that before, but using it like this would be ripping their code.

Comment: And including that library in your application is an option? (`from dpkt.netbios import decode_name`)

Comment: I'm trying to build an open source program which doesn't require any external module !
But thanks for you suggestion, appreciated :)